# Can I play multiplayer Minecraft for Wii U on LAN?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console, wii-u

I have 2 Wii Us that has Minecraft installed on the same LAN. Can me and my friend play Minecraft together on 1 LAN server?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is too late, but yes.

Comment: Any source for that? Or maybe explain how to do it?